# Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cultureinfo

**Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?**

We have the name of the culture stored in a database, and when our application starts, we do

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(theCultureString);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

But, of course, this gets "lost" when we want to do something in a new thread. Is there a way of setting that `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` for the whole application? So that new threads also gets that culture? Or is it some event fired whenever a new thread is created that I can hook up to?

Comment: If you are using resources, you can manually force it by: Resource1.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr"); This way every time you want to retrieve a string, it is localized and returned

Answer (score 207, accepted):

In .NET 4.5, you can use the [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx) property to change the culture of an AppDomain.

For versions prior to 4.5 you have to use reflection to manipulate the culture of an AppDomain.  There is a private static field on `CultureInfo` (`m_userDefaultCulture` in .NET 2.0 mscorlib, `s_userDefaultCulture` in .NET 4.0 mscorlib) that controls what `CurrentCulture` returns if a thread has not set that property on itself.

This does not change the native thread locale and it is probably not a good idea to ship code that changes the culture this way.  It may be useful for testing though.

Comment: Be careful with this setting in ASP.NET applications. Setting the culture on the AppDomain will set the culture for all users. So it's not going to be good for english user to see the web site in german for example.

Comment: I inherited an ASP.NET application that only works if all cultures are in en-US. This is a scenario where this setting is perfect for the time until that flaw is fixed

Comment: I used to have a MVC filter where I set the culture on the current thread. But after upgrading from .NET 4.5 to 4.8 JSON serialization seems to be happening on a different thread where the culture was not the same as set in the filter. I'm sceptical if this solution would reliably work in a ASP.NET environment when you set the the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture in the filter too.

Answer (score 36):

This gets asked a lot. Basically, no there isn't, not for .NET 4.0. You have to do it manually at the start of each new thread (or `ThreadPool` function). You could perhaps store the culture name (or just the culture object) in a static field to save having to hit the DB, but that's about it.

Comment: kind of annoying... seems like you are right, hehe. So we do that now (and have the culture a static class), but we still have a problem with some threads that we do not have control over. Like processing threads in the microsoft report viewer. Found a work around though. Thank you for the info :)

Comment: This is really annoying :( It would be nice if there was a way to set the Current(UI)Culture automatically for your application and have all new threads pick up that value.

Comment: It's so long since I worked with this now so I don't remember exactly what we did. But I think it might have been that we instead of using dates in the dataset sent to the report viewer, we formatted the date into a string first, using the culture we had set in the application. Then it didn't really matter anymore that the report rendering threads used the wrong culture. So we didn't work around the problem with the threads using the wrong culture. We just worked around the problem of getting dates formatted wrongly :)

Comment: In our app, I tried "capturing" the threads (by calling a special method from certain places) and storing them in a collection for later use (in this case to set culture), which seems to be working to far.

Comment: Couldn't you store the cultureinfo object in session and (if you're using masterpages) check for it in your masterpage codebehind and set the current thread?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using resources, you can manually force it by:

```
Resource1.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr");
```

In the resource manager, there is an auto generated code that is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
/// </summary>
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
    get {
        return resourceCulture;
    }
    set {
        resourceCulture = value;
    }
}
```

Now every time you refer to your individual string within this resource, it overrides the culture (thread or process) with the specified resourceCulture.

You can either specify language as in "fr", "de" etc. or put the language code as in 0x0409 for en-US or 0x0410 for it-IT. For a full list of language codes please refer to: [Language Identifiers and Locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912040.aspx)

Comment: It can be "unforced" by setting it to Null: `Resource1.Culture = Null;`

Answer (score 14):

For .NET 4.5 and higher, you should use:

```cs
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: Apologize for maybe a dumb question, but where is supposed this code should be located?
This force absolutely all app run under culture  en-US?

Answer (score 6):

Actually you *can* set the default thread culture and UI culture, but only with Framework 4.5+

I put in this static constructor

```
static MainWindow()
{
  CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo
    .CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
  var dtf = culture.DateTimeFormat;
  dtf.ShortTimePattern = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International", "sShortTime", "hh:mm tt");
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

and put a breakpoint in the Convert method of a ValueConverter to see what arrived at the other end. CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture ceased to be en-US and became instead en-AU complete with my little hack to make it respect regional settings for ShortTimePattern.

Hurrah, all is well in the world! Or not. The culture parameter passed to the Convert method is *still* en-US. Erm, WTF?! But it's a start. At least this way

- you can fix the UI culture once when your app loads
- it's always accessible from `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`
- `string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now)` will use your customised regional settings

If you can't use version 4.5 of the framework then give up on setting CurrentUICulture as a static property of CultureInfo and set it as a static property of one of your own classes. This won't fix default behaviour of string.Format or make StringFormat work properly in bindings then walk your app's logical tree to recreate all the bindings in your app and set their converter culture.

Comment: Austin's answer already provided the insight that CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture can be set to change the culture of the AppDomain. CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture is to CurrentUICulture as CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture is to CurrentCulture.
There really is no reason to be getting the value directly from the registry in your code. If you want to change the CurrentCulture to some specific culture but retain the user overrides, then you just need to get the value from the CurrentCulture's DateTimeFormat's before you override it.

Comment: I will have to check but I seem to remember trying that without success, leading to getting it from the registry. Do you really think I would go to all that trouble for no reason? Registry access is a giant PITA in this brave new world of UAC.

Answer (score 4):

For ASP.NET5, i.e. ASPNETCORE, you can do the following in `configure`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("en-gb")),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-gb")
    },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-gb")
    }
});
```

Here's a series of blog posts that gives more information:

- [How ASP.NET 5 determines the culture settings for localization](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization/)
- Allowing user to set culture settings in ASP.NET 5:

  - [Part 1](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/allowing-user-to-set-culture-settings-aspnet5-part1/)
  - [Part 2](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/allowing-user-to-set-culture-settings-aspnet5-part2/)

Comment: I came searching for a way to do this in a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 site, and it's frustrating how easily I managed it with a different Core site in comparison! I'm in a multinational company, and for internal sites, all our formatting is en-US to prevent date confusion. But this legacy site is set up for en-US, en-CA and fr-CA. And in a "hack-y" way, so when I go to fix it, all of their type conversions blow up in the data layer! (French money values being "1 234,56 $"

Comment: @Sean your link is broken. Maybe it points to [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization/), [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/allowing-user-to-set-culture-settings-aspnet5-part1/) and [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/allowing-user-to-set-culture-settings-aspnet5-part2/)

Answer (score 4):

Working solution to set CultureInfo for all threads and windows.

1. Open **App.xaml** file and add a new "Startup" attribute to assign startup event handler for the app:

```
<Application ........
             Startup="Application_Startup"
>
```

2. Open **App.xaml.cs** file and add this code to created startup handler (Application_Startup in this case). The class App will look like this:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` are present in Framework 4.0 too, but they are Private. Using Reflection you can easily set them. This will affect all threads where `CurrentCulture` is not explicitly set (running threads too).

```
Public Sub SetDefaultThreadCurrentCulture(paCulture As CultureInfo)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.GetType().GetProperty("DefaultThreadCurrentCulture").SetValue(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, paCulture, Nothing)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.GetType().GetProperty("DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture").SetValue(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, paCulture, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked for me. 

Although using 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;            
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

Which looks the same didnt.
For clarity this is being used in a WPF app where the app itself was changing its culture however usercontrols in other projects were using the browser culture not the culture selected by the user

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit of expansion for @rastating's great answer. You can use the following code for all versions of .NET without any worries:

```
    public static void SetDefaultCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type type = typeof (CultureInfo);
        try
        {
            // Class "ReflectionContext" exists from .NET 4.5 onwards.
            if (Type.GetType("System.Reflection.ReflectionContext", false) != null)
            {
                type.GetProperty("DefaultThreadCurrentCulture")
                    .SetValue(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                        culture, null);

                type.GetProperty("DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture")
                    .SetValue(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                        culture, null);
            }
            else //.NET 4 and lower
            {
                type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultCulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    culture,
                    new object[] {culture});

                type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultUICulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    culture,
                    new object[] {culture});

                type.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultCulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    culture,
                    new object[] {culture});

                type.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultUICulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    culture,
                    new object[] {culture});
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for c# MVC:

1. First : Create a custom attribute and override method like this:

   ```
   public class CultureAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
           // Retreive culture from GET
           string currentCulture = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["culture"];

           // Also, you can retreive culture from Cookie like this :
           //string currentCulture = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value;

           // Set culture
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture);
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(currentCulture);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second : In App_Start, find FilterConfig.cs, add this attribute. (this works for WHOLE application)

   ```
   public class FilterConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
       {
           // Add custom attribute here
           filters.Add(new CultureAttribute());
       }
   }
   ```

That's it !

If you want to define culture for each controller/action in stead of whole application, you can use this attribute like this:

```
[Culture]
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
}
```

Or:

```
[Culture]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```