# Starting an NServiceBus Host project throws an error when trying to setup the SQLite DB for sagas

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus, system.data.sqlite

The `Init()` method on my `IWantCustomInitialization` implementor is

```
public void Init()
{
    NServiceBus.Configure.With()
        .Log4Net()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(false)
        .Sagas()
        .NHibernateSagaPersisterWithSQLiteAndAutomaticSchemaGeneration()
        .XmlSerializer(); 

}
```

The error is

> Database was not configured through Database method.  --->
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: **Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture.  Make sure " System.Data.SQLite.SR.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "System.Data.SQLite" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies requi red are loadable and fully
>   signed.**
>   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing
>   (String fileName)
>   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(Cultur
>   eInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents,
>   Boolean creat eIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   reques tedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents,
>   StackCrawlMark& stack Mark)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
>   cultur e, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
>   cultur e)    at System.Data.SQLite.SR.get_Keywords() in
>   c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.S QLite\SR.Designer.cs:line 87    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Schema_ReservedWords() in
>   c:\dev\sqlit e\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:line 1239
>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.GetSchema(String
>   collectionName, Strin g[] restrictionValues) in
>   c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnecti on.cs:line 1223
>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.GetSchema(String
>   collectionName) in c:
>   \dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:line 1176
>   at NHibernate.Dialect.Schema.AbstractDataBaseSchema.GetReservedWords()
>   at
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect
>   dia lect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)    at
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory
>   sessi onFactory)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping
>   mappi ng, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)    at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()    at
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()

Versions:

- NServiceBus 2.5.0.1496
- System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.74.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of SQLite for .NET is distributed as 2 dlls:

- System.Data.SQLite.dll
- SQLite.Interop.dll

Both dlls need to be present in the same folder as your EXE. Interop dll is platform specific so you have to manually (or Post-build) **copy x86 or x64** version.

Another thing to keep in mind is that **SQLite.Interop.dll** itslef depends on **MSVCR100.DLL** (part of Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package). You can get it here:

- [64 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523)
- [32 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

Note the SQLite for .NET 3.5 requires Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Runtime. You can confirm that Interop assembly has all the necessary dependencies using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Workaround for this issue can be found [here](http://mystuffisallhere.com/blog/post/2009/06/29/NHibernate-on-SQLite-30-e28093-a-workaround-for-e2809cCould-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culturee2809d.aspx). But it might be a good idea to resolve the issue without applying the workaround.

Comment: I know, I'm on a 64 bit machine, and I referenced the sqlite dll & post build step copied the interop.  I have the C++ package installed

Comment: I even tried using the 32 bit version just for kicks, it didn't work either

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it either unfortunately

Comment: I guess you will have to use Process Explorer and Dependency Walker to verify that all dependencies have been loaded.

Comment: Looks like your running in the Serbian? (SR) culture. Could you try to switch to english culture instead?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/c-setting-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-of-an-application