# How Can I Get the Current Short DateTime Format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get the sort DateTime format of the local system, in string format, using C#?

For example: `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/YYYY`

Comment: why do you want to know why he wants to know ? :D

Comment: @Davide Because new questioners 2 out of 3 times don't know what they want? Perhaps he simply needs `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Globalization;

...
...
...

var myDTFI = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

var result = myDTFI.FullDateTimePattern;
```

Comment: OP: sorry I gave you the example with the FULL pattern, of course you can also get the short one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Overkill but should do it:

```
CultureInfo info = null;

var thread = new Thread(() => {
    info = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    return;
});

thread.Start();
thread.Join();

// info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Based on the fact that new threads should inherit the standard culture of the system (I consider it a missing feature: it's nearly impossible to control the culture of new threads, read here [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/c-setting-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-of-an-application)). I'm not directly using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` because someone could have messed with it :-)