# DateTime.ToLongTimeString() generates different strings

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I use `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()` to get the current time string.

However it behaves weird, sometimes it returns time like `3:10:00` and sometimes like `03:10:00` (leading zero). Why this happens?

I set a culture on application startup

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(...);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(...);
```

And the different result for the time string comes from a Task (from what I can see now). So I create a Task and `.Wait()` for it to finish. Inside the task the time is converted to string differently.

**UPDATE**

For those who are interested, here is some helpful reading I found:

[Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/setting-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-of-an-application)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx

Comment: Well are you changing the `Culture` anytime anywhere ?

Comment: This is the danger of changing the UI thread's culture.  A worker thread ruins your day.  Yes, .NET 4.5 has a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However it behaves weird, sometimes it returns time like 3:10:00 and sometimes like 03:10:00 (leading zero).

You haven't said anything about *where* this happens - but it could certain happen if you use different cultures. Normally without the leading zero I'd expect to see an am/pm designator as well though.

If you want consistent results, always specify the same culture (e.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).

Of course, if this has all been on the same system without changing culture settings, that's a different matter.

Comment: This happens when I call `.ToLongTimeString()` from a Task, i.e. from the main thread it returns "03" and from the Task it returns "3". For the main thread I specify a culture at application startup. Seems I need to pass the main thread's culture to the task. I thought it would pick the culture automatically.

Comment: @net_prog: No, I don't believe culture is propagated either. (I'd have expected it to be too, but I just recently learned that it *isn't* part of the `ExecutionContext`, although it probably should be.)