# Set default thread culture for all thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture of an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/setting-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-of-an-application)

I want to set a default culture for every thread that i open in my application.
Is there a way to set it (without setting it on every thread individually)

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

if you are using .net 4.5 you can use the below property

`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` Property

*In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture. For applications whose current culture differs from the default system culture, this behavior is often undesirable. In the .NET Framework 4.5, the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property enables an application to define the default culture of all threads in an application domain.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx

Comment: Any idea how this affects IIS threads in w3wp? If each user thread has a different culture, can each of those have a default culture for new sub-threads that get spawned?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a static helper class that constructs your threads with the default culture if your choice, if you are not using .NET 4.5.