# Execute task with the CurrentCulture set to the Task creator CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, cultureinfo

I've an application where we use Tasks. We also modified the cultureInfo(we use the EN-US language, but keep the date/number format), and we use .Net 4.0.

The application has a lot of thread and task, and we have a factory for the creation of Task/Threads.

For the thread, we have the following code, to ensure that every thread is launched with the correct CurrentCulture:

```
//This is basically only the constructor, but it describe well how we create the Thread:
public MonitoredThread(ThreadStart threadStart, string name, bool isBackground = false)
{
    m_threadStart = threadStart;
    m_name = name;
    m_isBackground = isBackground;
    Thread = new Thread(ThreadWorker)
    {
        Name = name,
        IsBackground = isBackground,
        CurrentCulture = CustomCultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        CurrentUICulture = CustomCultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    };
}
```

But for the Tasks, I don't know how to implement this kind of mechanism:

```
public static Task ExecuteTask(Action action, string name)
{
    MonitoredTask task = new MonitoredTask(action, name);
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(task.TaskWorker);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What Type is `TaskWorker` ?

Comment: `MonitoredTask` is a custom class representing a `Task`(we trace them when they starts, when they finish, etc... `TaskWorker` is a property giving access to the `Task` mapped by this class

Comment: Made an error, `TaskWorker` is the Action that we gave in parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Though late, but best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536117/1662459

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal "and we use .Net 4.0."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not sure you really need a `MonitoredTask` for this. You can capture the custom culture using closure:

```
public static Task ExecuteTask(Action action, string name)
{
   var customCulture = CustomCultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   {
       // use customCulture variable as needed
      // inside the generated task.
   });
}
```

Another way of doing this would be to pass the current culture as `object state` using the proper overload (either `Action<object>` or `Func<object, TResult>`):

```
public static Task ExecuteTask(Action action, string name)
{
   var customCulture = CustomCultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
   return Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => 
   {
       var culture = (CultureInfo) obj;
       // use customCulture variable as needed
      // inside the generated task.
   }, customCulture);
}
```

I would definitely go with the former.

For more on closure, see [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

Comment: Well in fact, the MonitoredTask already wraps the "action", and the provided Action "TaskWorker" already makes some changes(like register that a new task has started, log any errror happening during it's execution. So I was able to set the CurrentCulture directly in this part. Sorry for the wasted time, but you pointed me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 3):

From .Net 4.5, you can set a default culture for all threads in the current application domain ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

this way you have a unified culture for all tasks and thread in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more detail to @Yuval Itzchakov answer, I normally create some extension methods for the `TaskFactory` class that preserve the Culture (I normally also add one that receives an action that sets any given property to the executing thread:

```
#region StartNewWithPersistedCulture methods

public static Task<TResult> StartNewWithPersistedCulture<TResult>(
    this TaskFactory taskFactory, Func<TResult> function, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions creationOptions = default (TaskCreationOptions))
{
    if (taskFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("taskFactory");
    if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("function");

    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    return taskFactory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUICulture;

            return function();
        }, cancellationToken, creationOptions, TaskScheduler.Default);
}

public static Task StartNewWithPersistedCulture(
    this TaskFactory taskFactory, Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions creationOptions = default (TaskCreationOptions))
{
    if (taskFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("taskFactory");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    return taskFactory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUICulture;

            action();
        }, cancellationToken, creationOptions, TaskScheduler.Default);
} 

#endregion
```