# How to run a Task under a given culture?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task

I'd like to run a TPL `Task` under a given culture. I have an `Action` and a `CultureInfo` and want to run those in a `Task`. This is for unit testing purposes.

I could set `Thread.CurrentCulture` inside of the task but my concern is that the culture will "leak" and affect other thread pool work items that will non-deterministically reuse the current thread.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Are you doing this in an actual manually created thread, or because you are using C# async?

Comment: I hope to avoid using manual threads. I hope to make use of tasks because they compose better. Basically, I want to run some work in parallel in a few tasks. The task code is culture sensitive and multiple cultures will be used.

Comment: I think your best choice is this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012508/execute-task-with-the-currentculture-set-to-the-task-creator-currentculture