# Handling decimal separators (comma and dot) for a whole program with few lines of code

Tags: c#, decimal, regional-settings

I'm trying to make my program more compatible, for that I've ended up changing a lot of little things for example,

Using `textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(value)` instead of `= "value"`

Getting the current user decimal separator and using it `replace` on a `tryparse`

```
char sepdec = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

float.TryParse(str.Replace(",", sepdec.ToString()).Replace(".", sepdec.ToString()), out testvariable;
```

But these solutions are hard to implement when you have already coded most of your program without worrying about it.

So I'm trying to find ways to make the whole code compatible, without having to edit every `tryparse` and every `textbox`

I've tried to do the following:

```
//Get the current user decimal separator before the program initializes
char sepdec = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

//Create a current culture clone and change the separator to whatever the user has in his regional options, before the initializing the component

  public Form1()
  {
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = sepdec.ToString();

  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

  InitializeComponent();
  }
```

But I've tested this, and it's not really doing anything. Wasn't it supposed to make the program understand something like `ok, now you use dot as your decimal separator altough you have values in textBox as "2,5"`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok, now you use dot as your decimal separator altough you have values
>   in textBox as "2,5"

Exactly.

`float.TryParse` method uses your `CurrentCulture` settings if you don't use any `IFormatProvider` with it.

If you try to parse `"2,5"` to float without any `IFormatProvider`, your `CurrentCulture` has to have `,` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator`.

If you try to parse `"2.5"` to float, you either use a culture as an another parameter which already has . as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx)), or you can `.Clone()` your `CurrentCulture` (as you did) and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to `.` and use this cloned culture as an another parameter in [`float.TryParse` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly because it doesn't work. When I say `ok, now you use dot as your decimal separator altough you have values in textBox as "2,5"` What I mean is`you will now treat "2,5" as "2.5" (with a dot), and tryparse it correctly`.

Comment: Also, I might be wrong again, but this could be the issue. When I say `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;` Shouldn't every `tryparse` in the code use that customculture? Because if I have to use `currentculture` as a argument, it will defeat the purpose of avoiding editing every `tryparse`

Comment: @ng80092b No. A culture _can't_ treat `2,5` as `2.5` or vice versa. A float can have different representation as a string based on culture settings. This is the same as when you try parse a string to float. Your string needs to exact separators that used in current culture for parsing operation.

Comment: @ng80092b For your second comment, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a