# How to set CultureInfo for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime

Seems like people are not getting the whole tag concept. Before you mark this as a duplicate, understand that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` does not exist in **WinRT/Windows Runtime**.

Want to test following code with a culture other than the default:

```
public string Now =>
    DateTime.Now.ToString("g", new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name));
```

So far,

```
[UITestMethod]
public void UI_NowIsLocalizable()
{
    // Arrange
    Clock clock = new Clock();
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
    string expected = DateTime.Now.ToString("g");

    // Act
    string actual = clock.Now;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

While debugging the test, `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` still shows us-en and the test passes (should fail).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a)

Comment: why aren't you just passing `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: @JonathonChase not a duplicate - WinRT is different.

Comment: You ought to check it first against the ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages list.  Low odds in a unit test no doubt.

Comment: How come not to fake the `CurrentInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` ?  That sounds more reasonable as it's a dependency for your method.