# DataTextFormatString DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having an issue with using DataTextFormatString property where the values are not actually being formatted when they are being bound to the drop down list.

```
dvWaterLimits = this._lookupProvider.GetDataTable(version, form, package, state, DateTime.Today(), Zone);
this.ddlMyDropDown.DataSource = dvWaterLimits;
this.ddlMyDropDown.DataTextField = "LimitDescription";
this.ddlMyDropDown.DataValueField = "TotalLimit";
this.ddlMyDropDown.DataTextFormatString = " {0:$###,###,##0} ";
this.ddlMyDropDown.DataBind();
```

The data table I am getting back looks like the following:
Where the second column is the `TotalLimit` and the fifth column is `LimitDescription`

```
1133    5000    2   3   $5000 
1133    10000   2   3   $10000 
1133    15000   2   3   $15000 
1133    20000   2   3   $20000 
1133    25000   2   3   $25000
```

And the Drop down looks just like the fifth column when it should look like $5,000 $10,000... etc. with the commas.

Comment: What about {0:($ #,#)} as the format?

Comment: nope still the same, I have tried other formats just to see it change to like {0:C}

Comment: What about adding string.Format(0:($ #,#))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not sure if it was the '$', or if the value was coming in as a string so it couldn't make the match between the # and the value coming in. But this started working after i made this ineffecient change.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtClone.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["LimitDescription"].ToString().Contains("$"))
                {
                    dr["LimitDescription"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["LimitDescription"].ToString().Replace("$", "")).ToString("$###,###,##0");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

use C in your format string.

```
{0:C}
```

C or c
[Displays numeric values in currency format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx). You can specify the number of decimal places.

Note: a comma is not used in US for decimals!

Comment: I _always_ forget that I can specify the precision with as `"C0"` so instead of setting `CurrencyDecimalDigits` property :(

Answer (score 1):

One option can be override your `CurrentCulture` for this operation with cloned `en-US` culture which setted [`CurrencyDecimalDigits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx) to `0` and use [The `"C"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) for `DataTextFormatString` property as `"{0:C}"`.

It is unclear you want as `$5,000` or `$5000`. If you don't want group separator, you need to assign `CurrencyGroupSeparator` to empty string as well.

As an example;

```
int i = 5000;
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("C", clone)); // $5,000
```

or

```
int i = 5000;
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("C", clone)); // $5000
```

Or *much* better without setting `CurrencyDecimalDigits` property;

```
int i = 5000;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))); // $5,000
```

I honestly don't know how to override a culture for *just* one element in asp.net (or possible or not) but you can check these topics;

- [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a)
- [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)