# Deserialization decimal with invariant culture

Tags: c#, decimal, deserialization, invariantculture

Is it possible to deserialize decimal with invariant culture?

I can do that with this pattern:

```
 [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal CurrencyValue { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("CurrencyValue")]
    public string CurrencyValueString
    {
        set { CurrencyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
```

But my container consists of many decimals and I'm embarrassed doing this many times. Moreover it's look strange.

Answer (score 0):

You could decide to use the InvariantCulture as a default for the current thread, or for the whole application, using CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, if you're on .Net 4.5.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a) for informations.

Answer (score -1):

I made a test

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(decimal));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var row = XElement.Parse(@"<decimal>321,64</decimal>");
        using (var xmlReader = row.CreateReader())
        {
           var result = (decimal)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
```

Unfortunetely this throws exception but the second example returns 32164(BTW. is it good result? )

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        var row = XElement.Parse(@"<string>321,64</string>");
        using (var xmlReader = row.CreateReader())
        {
           var result = (string)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
           decimal s = Convert.ToDecimal(result,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
```

Comment: this will get you a result of 32164 and not 321.64