# How to keep same date format after changing the language culture?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, cultureinfo

Date format is changing based on the culture when I am using `DateTime.ParseExact()` method.

I want to keep date in `en-US` culture always. Please see the below code I am  using.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("21072016 10:12:20", 
                               "ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                               new CultureInfo("en-US",false));

string ff = date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

When changing culture to `ar` it is converting date as in arabic calendar (16101437 10:12:20).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/468791/447156 ?

Comment: A `DateTime` just stores the number of 100ns intervals that have happened since midnight at the start of January 1st 0001. It doesn't remember *any* string or culture settings which may have been used in the process of constructing it.

Comment: but when I am using above code with culture "ar" , the date become "16101437 10:12:20" (based on arabic calendar)

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");   
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInfo;
```

Comment: add this code in  your Global.asax in Application_BeginRequest method

Comment: but my application is working based on the language selected (arabic/english).