# Format DateTime to local string with a timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I need to be able to get the current date as string in different formats.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, timeZone);
Console.WriteLine(localTime.ToShortDateString());
```

The example above prints the date as `22-01-2018`, which is the danish format. But I need it to print the date as `1/22/2018` (example only).

I know that I can format dates using `ToString`, but I need to be able to format the date from a range of different timezones (the user picks the timezone).

Can I somehow tell `ToShortDateString` to use another culture and if so, how do I get from `TimeZoneInfo` to `CultureInfo`?

Comment: You can change the culture of your current thread or of the whole application. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a

Comment: @ThomasVoß Why? You can simply give it as parameter to DateTime.ToString(...) without changing _all_ aspects for your thread/app. Yours is better suited if you want to have a world-wide app, thats completely set to one TZ/culture or the other instead of having outputs for different cultures

Comment: I'm not sure there is a reliable real-world mapping from Time Zone to preferred date format. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.100).aspx) discusses how to carry out culture-specific formatting, but it may be that it's not possible to infer culture from TZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly convert `TimeZoneInfo` to `CultureInfo` unfortunately.

The problem is that in any given timezone there are many countries which fall into it and hence **many different culture settings**.

The awesome [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) by Jon Skeet includes country code -> timezone mappings so you could use that to know which countries are in your given time zone. But from there, you will have to choose the target country somehow.