# ExcelDataReader does not read floats with comma like "123,45" (instead reads "123.45")

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

How can I read float values with comma like `123,45`?

I have to read third party excel files that come formatted like `123,45` and I can not / am not allowed to reformat them to `123.45`.

I am now using this method:

```
    string GetCell(int row, int col)
    {
        if (Sheet != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string cellContent = Sheet[row][col].ToString(); // careful "ToString()" syntax!
                //Print("Excel.Get({0},{1}): {2}", row, col, cellContent);
                return cellContent;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Print("Excel.Get("+row+","+col+") error: "+ e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Print("Excel.Get("+ row + ","+ col+") error: sheet is null");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but the string is returned as `12345`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can read (parse) "123,45" as `12345` or `123.45`...  which way you like? (please [edit] post to clarify)

Comment: read them by setting a culture / locale that use commas as decimal separator, like French language/culture for instance.

Comment: I still don't get which result you want... Anyway as @Pac0 said pick a culture and [set it for current thread or whole process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a). Pick culture that either treats `,` as decimal separator (to get `123.45`) or group separator (to get `12345`)

Comment: yes, set the Culture for current thread, or use float.Parse with the culture argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to specify a culture

```
    string valueRead = "123,45";
    CultureInfo frenchCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    float valueParsed = float.Parse(valueRead, frenchCultureInfo);
```

EDIT : as per your comment, you can specify the culture using the Excel interop. Other choices include, read values as string and use `float.Parse`, or change the culture of the current thread.

I used French because comma is a decimal separator in this language, but of course any other language for which it's the case should fit.

Comment: Thanks! it worked putting `CultureInfo frenchCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR")` at the beginning of my `Excel` class