# Register CultureInfo for the duration of the application

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

Is there a way to register a [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) only for the current process?
I know the [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.register?view=netframework-4.8) method can do it permanently, but I don't want to do persist it or to have the application require administrative privileges.

I want to be able to create a custom culture, assign it a name and then retrieve it using that name, like:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("X-myTestName");
```

The reason is that I think a third party library is passing the current culture name to a thread it creates.

Comment: Save it in a config file and retrieve when necessary?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536117/3791245) help?

Comment: @Sach I'm not interested in retrieving it my code; I think a third party library is doing something like:
var culture = new CultureInfo(Threading.Thread.CultureInfo.Name) 
and Threading.Thread.CultureInfo is a custom culture with a made up name.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I can try it next week, but probably not. Check the comment to Sach above.

Comment: I think I see.  The link I posted is more for setting a culture as the default for threads in your AppDomain, but you want to _create a new culture option_, presumably to match the string "with a made up name" from your 3rd party library.  All answers I can find on SO point to using `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register()` as _the_ way to create a custom CultureInfo.  Not really seeing other options.