# Generic parser with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, azure

I have the code below for parsing different types. However I realized when deploying to Azure the double etc was different on my local PC. My best bet is due to CultureInfo. I would like to add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to the code below. However I have not found a way to do this via the delegate approach. Any pointers how to fix this? Or is it not possible for all the types and I need to handle each type differently?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Common.Parse
{
    public delegate bool ParseDelegate<T>(string s, out T result);

    public static class TryParseExtensions
    {
        public static int? TryParseOrDefaultInt32(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<int>(value, int.TryParse);
        }

        public static Int16? TryParseOrDefaultInt16(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<Int16>(value, Int16.TryParse);
        }

        public static Int64? TryParseOrDefaultInt64(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<Int64>(value, Int64.TryParse);
        }

        public static byte? TryParseOrDefaultByte(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<byte>(value, byte.TryParse);
        }

        public static bool? TryParseOrDefaultBoolean(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<bool>(value, bool.TryParse);
        }

        public static Single? TryParseOrDefaultSingle(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<Single>(value, Single.TryParse);
        }

        public static Double? TryParseOrDefaultDouble(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<Double>(value, Double.TryParse);
        }

        public static float? TryParseOrDefaultFloat(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<float>(value, float.TryParse);
        }

        public static Decimal? TryParseOrDefaultDecimal(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<Decimal>(value, Decimal.TryParse);
        }

        public static DateTime? TryParseOrDefaultDateTime(this string value)
        {
            return TryParseOrDefault<DateTime>(value, DateTime.TryParse);
        }

        public static int TryParseInt32(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<int>(value, int.TryParse);
        }

        public static Int16 TryParseInt16(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<Int16>(value, Int16.TryParse);
        }

        public static Int64 TryParseInt64(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<Int64>(value, Int64.TryParse);
        }

        public static byte TryParseByte(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<byte>(value, byte.TryParse);
        }

        public static bool TryParseBoolean(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<bool>(value, bool.TryParse);
        }

        public static Single TryParseSingle(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<Single>(value, Single.TryParse);
        }

        public static Double TryParseDouble(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<Double>(value, Double.TryParse);
        }

        public static Decimal TryParseDecimal(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<Decimal>(value, Decimal.TryParse);
        }

        public static DateTime TryParseDateTime(this string value)
        {
            return TryParse<DateTime>(value, DateTime.TryParse);
        }

        public static T TryParse<T>(this string value, ParseDelegate<T> parse) where T : struct
        {
            T result;
            parse(value, out result);
            return result;
        }

        public static T? TryParseOrDefault<T>(this string value, ParseDelegate<T> parse) where T : struct
        {
            T result;
            var succeed = parse(value, out result);

            if (succeed)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add delegates having `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` parameters.

But the question is, why do you need to make the delegate approach public? For the rare cases that are not covered by your non-delegate methods, you could also use an approach based on [Convert.ChangeType(Object, Type, IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_System_IFormatProvider_) instead.

```
public static T? TryParseOrDefault<T>(this string value) where T : struct
{
    try {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also note that `Single` and `float` are the same. `TryParseOrDefaultFloat` is redundant.

Comment: I really like this approach. However I get an error saying cannot convert from culture to type.

Comment: I was missing the type parameter. I added `typeof(T)` now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to solve it with a single `delegate`, because the types that your parser handles don't share a `TryParse` with a common signature that accepts an `IFormatProvider` (in your case, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).

For instance, the [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) and [`Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Double__) culture-aware parsing methods have different parameters order and type:

```cs
// Note the DateTimeStyles type
bool DateTime.TryParse(string? s, IFormatProvider? provider, DateTimeStyles styles, out DateTime result);

// Note the different order and NumberStyles type
bool Double.TryParse(string? s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider? provider, out double result);
```

Have you considered specifying the culture at the thread level? Something like this:

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

Just beware that it won't affect only this class, but [the entire thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-5.0).

If this is part of an ASP.NET application, you can even [change the culture at the application level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/set-current-culture#application-level).